# How to create a findAll() method in android

Tags: android, sqlite, dao

How to create a **findAll()** in android ? I've tried this but I can not achieve it ;

> public List findAll() {
>       Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery( "select * from " + TABLE_NAME, "", "" ); }

Here is Medicament.java

```
public class Medicament {
    private long   id;
    private String nom;
    private String fabriquant;
    private String pharmacie;
    private String description;
    private float prix;

    public Medicament( long id, String nom, String fabriquant, String pharmacie, String description, float prix ) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.fabriquant = fabriquant;
        this.pharmacie = pharmacie;
        this.description = description;
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom( String nom ) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getFabriquant() {
        return fabriquant;
    }

    public void setFabriquant( String fabriquant ) {
        this.fabriquant = fabriquant;
    }

    public String getPharmacie() {
        return pharmacie;
    }

    public void setPharmacie( String pharmacie ) {
        this.pharmacie = pharmacie;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription( String description ) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public float getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }

    public void setPrix( float prix ) {
        this.prix = prix;
    } }
```

**EDIT:** Please do not forget the return statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it even compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somethiing like that in Your SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public List<Medicament> findAll() {
    List<Medicament> medicaments = new ArrayList<Medicament>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Medicament medicament = new Medicament();

            /*fill here medicament object with values from row, 
            cursor.getString(0) = id value, cursor.getString(1) etc...
            for example medicament.setName(cursor.getString(1))*/

            medicaments.add(medicament);

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return medicaments;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Remember to use methods properly for value type in a cell, for example for `Integer` values use `cursor.getInt(COLUMN_NUMBER)`, for `String` `cursor.getString(COLUMN_NUMBER)` etc.

Comment: Thanks very much, another easy questions : what kind of methods can I put in a SQLiteOpenHelper class ? Can't I simply put it in another DAO class that extends a DAODatabase class, please ?

Comment: @rzqr for example methods to add Medicament to table, remove etc. Create separate class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database) You have realy simple example how to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: but, it is not a good practice in Android to use the DAO pattern or it's unnecessary ?

Comment: @rzqr it is very good practice. For example if You modify database other parts of your app shouldn't know about it, they just use your simple interface to communicate with a database.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery( "select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);
```

Comment: what about the return statement, please ?

Comment: post the complete code dude how would I know which fields are in your table and how your class "Medicament" looks. You post the query then I think you are stuck with the query. So please define question precisely and where your are stuck with.